# Using a dictionary's update function

Tags: python, class, dictionary

I have a question regarding the built in update function for dictionary

```
mydict = {1: {45:'ades'}, 2: {68:'gdes'}}
addthis = {1: {44:'paes'}}
changethis = {1: {45 : 'qwes'}
mydict.update(new)
mydict.update(changethis)
>>>mydict
{1: {45: 'qwes'}, {44: 'paes}, 2:{68: 'gdes'}}
```

I am familiar with the fact that update replaces whatever key and it's values attached to it if it already exists. However, I was wondering how I could append `addthis` without removing my original key of 1, then update with `changethis` replace the original key of 1. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: In python dictionary keys must be unique!!

Comment: you want that for the key 1, you will access 2 different values? or that you will access with 1 to a different dictionary?

Comment: Hi @Green, I want that key 1 will access two different values, which are dictionaries

Comment: @Ahmad Really? So this is impossible?

Comment: Do you want the result to be: `{1: {44: 'paes', 45: 'qwes'}, 2: {68: 'gdes'}}`? Because the desired result in your question is invalid.

Comment: You want to append `{44:'paes'}` as {1: [{45:'ades'}, {44:'paes'}]} ?

Comment: Yes, I would like it if I could access two values with key 1

Comment: Yes sir @AmitTripathi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<strike>It appears from the comments that you want a list. To do that, each value of your map needs to be a list, rather than a single dictionary.</strike>

```
mydict = {1: [{45:'ades'}], 2: [{68:'gdes'}]}
```

Then, when you add things to `mydict`, you need to index into the dictionary and update:

```
addthis = {44:'paes'}
mydict[1].append(addthis)

>>>mydict
{1: [{45: 'ades'}, {44: 'paes'}], 2: [{68: 'gdes'}]}
```

And to change things in `mydict`, you will need to iterate over the items in the list and update accordingly:

```
for el in mydict[1]:
    if 45 in el.keys():
        el[45] = 'qwes'
        break
```

Which will result in:

```
>>>mydict
{1: [{45: 'qwes'}, {44: 'paes'}], 2: [{68: 'gdes'}]}
```

---

After further clarification, it appears that you want a dictionary of dictionaries:

```
mydict = {1: {45: 'ades'}, 2: {68: 'gdes'}}
```

To add an element to `1` in your dictionary:

```
mydict[1][44] = 'paes'
>>>mydict
{1: [{44: 'paes', 45: 'ades'}], 2: [{68: 'gdes'}]}
```

You can access the value at `44` using:

```
mydict[1][44]
```

To modify the value at `45`:

```
mydict[1][45] = 'qwes'
>>>mydict
{1: {44: 'paes', 45: 'qwes'}, 2: {68: 'gdes'}}
```

Comment: Um... thank you for helping out. Is there a way to somehow link an element in a list to a value? This is because if I need to append a bunch of elements into my key 1's value list, how am I going to know which element is the one I need? For instance, if I needed to append 100 items into the list, I need an easy way to just say "45" then it pulls out the value for key 45.

Comment: Your other alternative is to have a dictionary of dictionaries (rather than a dictionary of list of dictionaries). That would look like `{1: {45: 'qwes', 44: 'paes'}, 2: {68: 'gdes'}}` and would be accessed like: `mydict[1][45] == 'qwes'` and `mydict[1][44] == 'paes'`.

Comment: Yes! This is what I need! However, I am stuck as to how I can append a key's value and the value's value into a dictionary without wiping out whatever I had to start with and replacing it.

Comment: How come you initiated mydict without brackets then somehow included brackets and somehow removed them again?

Comment: The brackets in this context are used to index into (access a value in) the dictionary. They do not represent a list. When I do something like `mydict[1][45]` I am indexing into entry `1` of `mydict` and then indexing into entry `45` of that sub-dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

if I understood you correctly, this what you need in order to have a dictionary with the value to the key **"1"** is also a dictionary :

```
test_dict = {1: {45:"t"}, 2:{44:"tt"}}
new_value = {1: {44: "pae"}}
update_value = {1:{44:"tt"} }


def add_to_dict(dict, new_value):
   for key, value in new_value.items():
       dict[key].update(value)
# print(new_value.keys())

def update_dict(dict,new_value):
    dict.update(new_value)


if _name_ == '_main_':

   add_to_dict(test_dict,new_value)
   print(test_dict)
   update_dict(test_dict,update_value)
   print(test_dict)
```

it will print:

```
# after you add a value to the dictionary inside the dictionary
{1: {44: 'pae', 45: 't'}, 2: {44: 'tt'}}
# after you update the value
{1: {44: 'tt'}, 2: {44: 'tt'}}
```

Comment: Oh! This is almost what I am looking for! But, if you could somehow not remove {1: {45: 't'}} after updating the dictionary, it would be perfect!

Comment: So just use the first function? sounds like this is what you want to achieve:  
{1: {44: 'pae', 45: 't'}, 2: {44: 'tt'}}